# client server android pc

Tags: android, client-server

I'm trying to do a simple client server application between an android device and my pc.
The client is running on my android device and server on my pc.
I have a no-ip address(dynamic ip updater) melu.no-ip.biz

Here is my simple server socket connection:

```
server = new ServerSocket(8181,100);
```

and here is my client connection:

```
connection = new Socket("melu.no-ip.biz",8181);
```

Does anyone know why it is not working? I just can't connect to the server. If I use the emulator and change the connection by:

```
connection = new Socket("10.0.2.2",8181);
```

It's working fine.
Also if I change it for

```
connection = new Socket("192.168.0.100",8181);
```

It's working.

But my application needs to work on my device and outside my local network. Any advices?

Comment: There are about a thousand things that could go wrong between here and there. I'm assuming you have a NAT router... do you have the port forwarded to your PC?

Comment: Yes the port 8181 is open on my pc and router

Comment: Who is the server, the PC or the Android device?

Comment: The android device is the client, server is on my pc

Comment: If `melu.no-ip.biz` is your actual hostname, you have a problem there - I wasn't able to resolve it, so no-ip may not be working as intended. On your computer, try `nslookup melu.no-ip.biz`.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone, god know's why but now it's working. Not on my actual device but it works on the emulator so I'll probably figure out how to make it work on the real device